# Flow cytometry representation of dot plots data in Cytospec 9.0

Tags: plot, bioinformatics, data-representation

From my University there are given some results from the flow cytometry analysis (fcs files).

My task is to run them on the cytospec programm, create gates and describe what type of lymphocytes they represent, in addition if they are pathological or not and what pathology do they have.

So my problem is that when I'm doing it, they are different from the ones that they need to do, even though I'm doing the same thing.

I have two pictures of the dot plots, the right one and mine.
[image: mine dot plot]

[image: the right one]

Answer (score 0):

Both look same to me, at least in some ways. The "right one" is having X and Y axis in the multiples of 1000 while your is absolute. In both the cases the X axis is going from 25000 to 260000. Because the "right one" is on the scale of multiples of 1000 so it extends from 25 to 260 but in "your" case it is going from 25000 to 260000 .. same is happening with Y axis. May be you need to normalize the data/area by applying appropriate multiples of 1000. By the way, you should post bioinformatics questions on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ for a better response (since you have tagged the question as bioinformatics).